# Unity netcode: Instantiated object gets declared only on server side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, server, client

I currently have a few days to do with a problem in netcode. I instantiate an object in my script and spawn it into my ServerRpc function as a client. The problem then is that my object ("instantiatedObj") is only declared on the server. So in the inspector you see as host that the client has this object declared but as a client you do not see that in the inspector. How could I solve the problem, i'm starting to pull my hair over it

```
public void SpawnObject() //SpawnObject gets executed when new player enter game
{
    if (IsOwner)
    {
        if (NetworkManager.Singleton.IsServer)
        {
            GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate(objTOInst, new Vector3(0.7110749f, 0.32f, -0.09f), transform.rotation);
            go.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();
            instantiatedObj = go;
        }
        else 
        {
            SpawnOnServerRpc();
        }
    }
}
[ServerRpc]
void SpawnOnServerRpc(ServerRpcParams rpcParams = default)
{
    instantiatedObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(objTOInst, new Vector3(0.7110749f, 0.32f, -0.09f), transform.rotation);
    instantiatedObj.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();     
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. The Object you are spawning must have a `NetworkObject` Component attached to it and must be assigned to the networked prefabs in the `NetworkManager` to let  `Netcode` know that this object when spawned has to be replicated across the network.
2. If you have spawned the GameObject already on the server side, `go.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();` It will automatically replicate on all the connected clients so **no need for else block**.
3. On Server if you want to send message to client use `ClientRpc` as @JohnMurphy pointed that out.
4. The object you are spawning is spawned with Server ownership, you can change that if you like -> `go.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().ChangeOwnership(clientId);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the **[ServerRPC]** to **[ClientRPC]**. The reasoning is because based on your code you are instantiating the game object on server regardless. If you are the **Owner** you are instantiating on the server, and if you are not the **Owner** you are still instantiating on the server because you are using the **ServerRPC** attribute above your method which makes the client instantiate a gameObject on the server. If you use **ClientRpc** then then the server would instantiate your game object on the **client(s)** for you instead of instantiating them on **Server**. Based on the code you have right now everything is being created on the **server** on not on any of the **clients**.

Comment: When I replace my ServerRpc function with a ClientRpc function, nothing happens, so the object is not instantiated or spawned.I think it is because only the server is allowed to use the ClientRpc function and I have to execute it through a ServerRpc but if I do this, then 2 objects are spawned at the client

Comment: I think your problem is you need to override the OnNetworkSpawn() method instead of using SpawnObject() method. You can probably put the [SeverRPc] how it was.
https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/tutorials/helloworld/helloworldtwo#adding-the-hellowworldplayercs-script

Comment: I did this but it still doesn't work. SpawnObject function is executed by the OnNetworkSpawn function which is overrideed     `    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        if (IsOwner)
        {
            SpawnObject();
        }
    }`